# How to calculate an overall mean from more than two columns in a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, mean, na

I would like to have a single mean value from my selected columns in a data frame, but it doesn't works from two columns.  I tried this:

```
testDF <- data.frame(v1 = c(1,3,15,7,18,3,5,NA,4,5,7,9),
                     v2 = c(11,33,55,7,88,33,55,NA,44,5,67,99),
                     v3 = c(NA,33,5,77,88,3,55,NA,4,55,87,14))

mean(testDF[,2:3], na.rm=T)
```

and I get this Warning message:

> mean(testDF[,2:3], na.rm=T)
>   [1] NA
>   Warning message:
>   In mean.default(testDF[, 2:3], na.rm = T) :
>   argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

if I use the `sum()` function it works perfectly, but I don't understand why it can't works with the `mean()` function. After some steps I did it with the `melt()` function from the `reshape2{}` package but I'm looking a short way to do it simple because I have a lot of variables and data.

Regards

Comment: You can also use `unlist()` instead of `as.matrix()`.

Comment: Or just use a matrix...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The help for `mean` says:

> Currently there are methods for numeric/logical vectors and date, date-time and time interval objects.

which makes me think that `mean` does not work on data frames.

Indeed you will see that doing `mean(testDF)` results in the same error, but `mean(testDF[,1])` works.

The easiest solution is to do:

```
mean(as.matrix(testDF[,2:3]), na.rm=T)
```

Also, you can use `colMeans` to get the mean of each column.

Indeed, if you look at the source for `colMeans`, the first lines are:

```
if (is.data.frame(x)) 
    x <- as.matrix(x)
```

Comment: I don't want to calculate `colMeans()` , however use `matrix()` or `unlist()` is great solution!